# Weird errors when using imshow

Tags: c++, opencv

I bought a new PC and tried to make a simple program do show a image.

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("fff.png");
    cout << img.rows << endl;
    cv::imshow("efef", img);
    cv::waitKey(1);
}
```

It works fine without the `imshow()`. With it I get this errors:

```
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\parallel\registry_parallel.impl.hpp (96) cv::parallel::ParallelBackendRegistry::ParallelBackendRegistry core(parallel): Enabled backends(3, sorted by priority): ONETBB(1000); TBB(990); OPENMP(980)
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\nox\source\repos\pb\pb\opencv_core_parallel_onetbb452_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_core_parallel_onetbb452_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\nox\source\repos\pb\pb\opencv_core_parallel_tbb452_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_core_parallel_tbb452_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\nox\source\repos\pb\pb\opencv_core_parallel_openmp452_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_core_parallel_openmp452_64d.dll => FAILED
```

I didn't build it myself, just downloaded the `exe` from GitHub. I tried the exact same thing on my laptop and it worked there. Building it from source code gets the same error.

Edit: After the third project it works. I don't know why though.

Comment: It's a debug build and thats surely not a debug mode output. It can't call imshow so it probably cant create a window.

Comment: dont mix debug and release lib/build. Make sure your code is built with same msvc runtime build (debug/release, threaded/nonthreaded, shared/static)

Comment: It _is_ a debug output. See here: https://forum.opencv.org/t/dlls-for-parallel-execution/3292

Comment: this problem is not yet solved. i am having the same issue.